# Web Scraping - McKinsey Articles

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am looking to scrape the article titles. I cannot figure out how to extract the title text. Can you please take a look at my code below and suggest solutions.

I am new to scrapy. I appreciate the help!

Screenshot of the web developer view of the web page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPn4W.jpg

```
import scrapy



class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.mckinsey.com/search?q=Agile&start=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.text-wrapper'):
            item = {
                'text': quote.css('h3.headline::text').extract(),
            }
            print(item)
            yield item
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks good for new-to-scrapy developer! I'd changed only selector in you `parse` function:

```
for quote in response.css('div.block-list div.item'):
    yield {
        'text': quote.css('h3.headline::text').get(),
    }
```

UPD: hm, looks like your website makes additional request for data.

Open developer tools and check request to `https://www.mckinsey.com/services/ContentAPI/SearchAPI.svc/search` with params `{"q":"Agile","page":1,"app":"","sort":"default","ignoreSpellSuggestion":false}`.
You can make `scrapy.Request` with these params and appropriate headers and get json with data. It will be easily parsed with `json` lib.

UPD2: as I can see from this curl `curl 'https://www.mckinsey.com/services/ContentAPI/SearchAPI.svc/search'  -H 'content-type: application/json' --data-binary '{"q":"Agile","page”:1,”app":"","sort":"default","ignoreSpellSuggestion":false}' --compressed`, we need to make request in this way:

```
from scrapy import Request
import json

data = {"q": "Agile", "page": 1, "app": "", "sort": "default", "ignoreSpellSuggestion": False}
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
url = "https://www.mckinsey.com/services/ContentAPI/SearchAPI.svc/search"
yield Request(url, headers=headers, body=json.dumps(data), callback=self.parse_api)
```

and then in `parse_api` function just parse response:

```
def parse_api(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    # and then extract what you need
```

So you can iterate parameter `page` in request and get all pages.

UPD3: Working solution:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
import json


class BrickSetSpider(Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"

    data = {"q": "Agile", "page": 1, "app": "", "sort": "default", "ignoreSpellSuggestion": False}
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    url = "https://www.mckinsey.com/services/ContentAPI/SearchAPI.svc/search"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.url, headers=self.headers, method='POST',
                  body=json.dumps(self.data), meta={'page': 1})

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        results = data.get('data', {}).get('results')
        if not results:
            return

        for row in results:
            yield {'title': row.get('title')}

        page = response.meta['page'] + 1
        self.data['page'] = page
        yield Request(self.url, headers=self.headers, method='POST', body=json.dumps(self.data), meta={'page': page})
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how i would make a request to the url above with the params you suggested?

Comment: @jwalman I've updated post with all the details. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have copied your code into my scraper.py. I now get the following error: SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function. I have copied your code exactly and am running it from command line with scrapy runspider scrapy.py. Can you please advise? Thank you so much for the help! I greatly appreciate it! -- @vezunchik

Comment: Did you insert yielding to `parse` function?

Comment: Can you please look at my code: https://imgur.com/a/pUAn9Xc? It still is not returning any text. What am i implementing incorrectly? I get the error: NameError: name 'scrapy' is not defined Thank you for the help! -- @vezunchik

Comment: Nope, your variants are incorrect. Refresh page and check UPD3, this is working solution.

Comment: Will be glad, if you accept answer and upvote solution :)

Comment: Under 15 reputation does not allow me to upvote. If its not too much to ask for could you show me the pagnation?  I have tried to increment the yeild line page integer but the results remain the same. Could you explain further? -- @vezunchik

Comment: Thank you! Is there anywhere i could privately message you? I have some more questions on how this works.What object is all the title text being stored in? If i wanted to extract additional text such as descriptions how would i do that? Thank you very much for your help! You are a Scrapy Pro!

Comment: Check `data` variable, there is more useful info. About questions: debug, learn scrapy tricks, and if you will fail, start another post with questions.

Comment: Once the scraper is done running i am left with the dict object data right? How would i then iterate through all the title's within the data object?

Comment: Is it possible to not have all data printed to output but be left with an array of articles?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `callback` parameter as well within the `Request()` located at the bottom-most in your `parse` method @vezunchik? Will be glad if you make it clear in comments. This one definitely deserves an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt Since we want to call `parse` method here, we can omit it, because it is in default values: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request `If a Request doesn’t specify a callback, the spider’s parse() method will be used. `

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to select text of h1 tag all you have to do is

```
[tag.css('::text').extract_first(default='') for tag in response.css('.attr')]
```

This is using the xpath, might be easier.

```
 //h1[@class='state']/text()
```

Also, I would recommend checking out BeautifulSoup for python. It is very easy and effective at reading entire html of page and extracting text. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

A very simple example would be like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<td><a href="http://www.fakewebsite.com">Please can you strip me?</a>
<br/><a href="http://www.fakewebsite.com">I am waiting....</a>
</td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

print(soup.get_text())
```